# Wso2 self registration page how to call rest api for autofill

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

In wso2 is 5.10 I wanted to populate fields based on api call response if the user inputs a field in self registration form. How to implement in self registration jsp page as the api should not be exposed at front-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may send the API request from the backend using JSP. So, this will be a call made by the server to the API endpoint and the API will not be exposed in the frontend.

Check out [How to Make Rest API call from a .jsp page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61337340/how-to-make-rest-api-call-from-a-jsp-page) to find an example of an API request from the server using Java.